# How to truncate a file while it is open with fstream

Tags: c++, std, fstream

I know it is possible to truncate a file with

```
std::fstream fs(mypath, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
```

but I need to read the file, truncate it, then write new contents all with the same file handle (so the whole operation is atomic). Anyone?

Comment: File streams don't allow this functionality AFAIK. You'll have to close and reopen the file stream with `trunc` to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think you can get "atomic" operation but using the [Filesystem Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) that has now been accepted as part of the [Standard Library (C++17)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) you can resize the file like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem> // compilers that support the TS
// #include <filesystem> // C++17 compilers

// for readability
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main(int, char*[])
{
    fs::path filename = "test.txt";

    std::fstream file(filename);

    if(!file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // display current contents
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << file.rdbuf();
    std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';

    // truncate file
    fs::resize_file(filename, 0);
    file.seekp(0);

    // write new stuff
    file << "new data";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

File streams don't support truncation except when opening a file. Also, the operations wouldn't be "atomic" anyway: at least, on POSIX systems you can happily read and write a file already opened by another process.

Answer (score -3):

C++ 11 supports swap on ofstream.  The best that I could imagine doing would be to open an empty file and call swap.  This would not be atomic, but as close as you can get.