# C++ fstream overwrite file

Tags: c++, fstream

This is my code (without error checking):

```
std::wfstream wfs("C:\\testfile.txt");
wfs.setf(std::ios_base::binary);
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << wfs.rdbuf();
wfs.seekp(0);
wfs << L"new";
```

Now, the first three characters in the file are replaced with "new".
However, I would like "new" to be the only contents of the file.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: `setf` takes format flags as an argument, not open mode flags. You want `std::wfstream wfs("C:\\testfile.txt", std::ios_base::binary)`.

Comment: Oh, then I also need to copy the default arguments such as `std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary` right?

Comment: No, they're automatically specified in `fstream`.

Comment: Please don't add answers to the question. If you want to answer your own question, that is fully possible by adding a new answer. The question box is just for the actual question.

Comment: Is that really a duplicate? That question specifies the read/trunk needs to be "atomic".

Comment: This is possible using the new [Filesystem Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs): **See:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/36020320/3807729

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wfs.setf(std::ios_base::binary,std::ios_base::trunc);
```

Comment: I had the impression that this erases the file before I can read; is this not correct?

Comment: yes, i thought this is what you want to do!

Comment: No, I first read the contents! Then overwrite the file. I thought the `seekp` followed by a `<<` would truncate it, but it doesn't.

Comment: why not after reading the contents, you close it and open it again with `trunc` enabled

Comment: Sure, that would be a workaround if it's not possible to get the stream to clear the file...