# How do I make and edit a list?

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to make my program read out a list in a .txt file, I created. It gets access and everything, but it always overwrites the previous inputs. How do I prevent that?
My goal is to have it read out previous sentences from the file and and add new one in the end if wanted. Currently I'm just struggling with the input part since I can't even get that to work.

I tried doing it by using
fstream file
file.open("text.txt")
file << "sentence" << endl

Also I tried the same with ofstrem with the same outcome.

Comment: You can't push something in the middle. You'll have to rewrite the entire file from the edit point until the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [replace text in middle of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922435/replace-text-in-middle-of-the-file)

Answer (score 0):

it would help if you used append before writing a new line.  can you try this method?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream file("text.txt", std::ios::app);

    if (file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";

        std::string sentence;
        std::getline(std::cin, sentence);

        file << sentence << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Sentence added to the file." << std::endl;

        file.close();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error opening the file." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this code:

std::ofstream file("text.txt", std::ios::app); opens the file in append mode, so new content will be added at the end of the file.

file << sentence << std::endl; writes the entered sentence to the file.

file.close(); closes the file when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read and write all at once in C++, what you can do is, first read the content from the file, like this:

```
// Create a text string, which is used to output the text file
string myText;

// Read from the text file
ifstream MyReadFile("filename.txt");

// Use a while loop together with the getline() function to read the file line by line
while (getline (MyReadFile, myText)) {
  // Output the text from the file
  cout << myText;
}

// Close the file
MyReadFile.close();
```

Make sure to close the file you are reading, after closing that file, open the same file in write mode, and write your data in it, you might want to add some conditions in it, whether this condition is true then write in the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Create and open a text file
  ofstream MyFile("filename.txt",ios::app);

  // Write to the file
  MyFile << "Files can be tricky, but it is fun enough!";

  // Close the file
  MyFile.close();
}
```

The new entries are always appended at the end of the file.
I hope this will help!

```
// Code from w3schools
```