# error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ifstream' and 'std::string')

Tags: c++, file, fstream, delete-file

I am currently trying to write data into a give file. I keep getting this error, even though I am using a `string` type:

> no match for no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ifstream' {aka 'std::basic_ifstream<char>'} and 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'})

Please also note: Entries are formatted like this:

```
-- new_password_name --
```

Here is my code:

```
void delete_entry()
{
    string delete_read;
    vector<string> show;
    vector<string> delete_entry;
    vector<string>::iterator new_end;
    string holder;
    string keeper;

    ifstream Display_File_Delete(stored_username + "names.txt");//NOTE:     I intend to overwrite this file
        
    while (getline (Display_File_Delete, holder)) // Read from the file into holder variable
        delete_entry.push_back(holder);//Adds holder to delete_entry vector

    for (int i = 0; i < delete_entry.size(); i++) { 
        if(delete_entry[i] == "-- " + new_password_name + " --"){//NOTE: new_password_name is a string inputed by the user who wishes to delete an entry
            new_end = remove(delete_entry.begin(), delete_entry.end(), "-- " + new_password_name + " --");//If an entry is found that matches the input, remove it. 
            delete_entry.erase(new_end,delete_entry.end());
        }
    }

    //write contents of new_end to entry file

    for (int i = 0; i < delete_entry.size(); i++){
        keeper = delete_entry[i];
        Display_File_Delete << keeper << endl; //Input the newly edited code back into the file.** <<!PROBLEMATIC LINE!>>**
    }

    Display_File_Delete.close();//Shuts the file
}
```

I tried using `ofstream`, but `getline()` takes `ifstream` inputs. `keeper` is a `string`, so I think that it should work.

**DESIRED EFFECT OF CODE:**
In case it is not clear, I'm trying to write `keeper` to the file.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and include the complete error message in the question

Comment: (mre probably means that you need to post less code, not more)

Comment: Typo: You want `>>` *not* `<<` -- `Display_File_Delete` is an input stream not an output stream.

Comment: @G.M Thanks for the response, however I don't think that's the error. EDIT: My goal is to write `keeper` to the file.

Comment: `ifstream Display_File_Delete(stored_username + "names.txt");` note that`ifstream` is an input file stream (meaning its for reading data from your file not writing) `ofstream` is for output. `fstream` is for reading or writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ifstream` is for **read-only input**. There is no overload of `operator<<` that can *write* to a `std::ifstream`.

`std::ofstream` is for **write-only output**. There is no overload of `std::getline()` that can *read* from a `std::ofstream`.

You are trying to **read** AND **write** to a file using a single stream object.  To do that correctly, you would need to use `std::fstream` with the `ios::in` and `ios::out` flags specified, eg:

```
fstream Display_File_Delete(stored_username + "names.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
```

Or simply (as `ios::in | ios::out` is the default mode):

```
fstream Display_File_Delete(stored_username + "names.txt");
```

However, your code currently reads in the whole file, erases the entries it doesn't want to keep, and then writes the remaining entries back to the same file.  If your goal is to *replace* the content of the existing file with just the entries you kept, removing the erased entries from the file, you can't do that with `std::fstream` alone, as [it does not let you truncate old data after the file is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809113/), thus if you erase any entries then you will be left with un-deleted data at the end of the file.

To account for that, you will have to use separate `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` objects instead (or, at least a single `std::fstream` with separate `open()` calls), letting `std::ofstream` (or `std::fstream(ios::out)`) truncate the file before writing the kept entries, eg:

```
ifstream Display_File_Delete(stored_username + "names.txt");
        
while (getline (Display_File_Delete, holder))
    delete_entry.push_back(holder);

Display_File_Delete.close();

...

ofstream Display_File_Update(stored_username + "names.txt");

for (size_t i = 0; i < delete_entry.size(); ++i){
    Display_File_Update << delete_entry[i] << endl;
}

Display_File_Update.close();
```

Or:

```
fstream Display_File;

Display_File.open(stored_username + "names.txt", ios::in);
        
while (getline (Display_File, holder))
    delete_entry.push_back(holder);

Display_File.close();

...

Display_File.open(stored_username + "names.txt", ios::out);

for (size_t i = 0; i < delete_entry.size(); ++i){
    Display_File << delete_entry[i] << endl;
}

Display_File.close();
```

Although, a safer approach would be to write the new data to a temporary file first, and only if that is successful then delete/rename the old file and rename the temporary file to the old name.  That way, if something goes wrong, you won't lose/corrupt your original data so you can recover and try again later.

---

On a side note, your `for` loop also suffers from another problem.  You are erasing entries from `delete_entry` while you are iterating through `delete_entry`.  Every time you erase an entry (and BTW, you are misusing `remove()`+`erase()` in this context), you are affecting your loop counter, which will cause the loop to skip entries.

The *correct* way to handle this is to either:

- don't increment your loop counter on any loop iteration that erases elements:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < delete_entry.size(); ) { 
    if (delete_entry[i] == "-- " + new_password_name + " --")
        delete_entry.erase(delete_entry.begin() + i);
    else
        ++i;
}
```

- use iterators instead:

```
auto iter = delete_entry.begin();
while (iter != delete_entry.end()) { 
    if (*iter == "-- " + new_password_name + " --")
        iter = delete_entry.erase(iter);
    else
        ++iter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind explaining how to specify `ios::in` and `std::out`?

Comment: Also, my code doesn't remove it from the file. Is that a separate question, or could you tell me why?

Comment: +2 for the additional help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @That_Coder "*my code doesn't remove it from the file. Is that a separate question, or could you tell me why?*" - I updated my answer.